# Why is my fieldset background-color so glitchy in Chrome when scrolling with overflow?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have used a fieldset of specific height for a form in my website and have set the overflow to auto.

When I apply background color to the fieldset, on scroll the background color and the content in fieldset looks weird on scrolling up and down.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5a8yLqwf/5/

This issue only occurs in Google Chrome.

```css
#fieldset {
background-color: grey;
width: 250px;
height: 150px;    
overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="page_content">
    <fieldset id="fieldset">
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
       
      </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: "Looks weird" how? Looks normal to me.

Comment: Looks like this is a Chrome-specific bug after looking a bit. Doesn't occur in Firefox, Edge (EdgeHTML or Chromium based), or IE11.

Answer (score 1):

Add `background-blend-mode: color` to `#fieldset`.

```css
#fieldset {
background-color: grey;
width: 250px;
height: 150px;    
overflow: auto;

background-blend-mode: color;
}
```

```html
<div id="page_content">
    <fieldset id="fieldset">
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
       
      </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add one more wrapper for fieldset. Make fieldset's background transparent, wrapper's background grey

```css
#fieldContainer{
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px; 
    background: grey;
    overflow: auto;
  
}
#fieldset {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="page_content">
  <div id="fieldContainer">
    <fieldset id="fieldset">
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
         1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
         1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
        3: <input type="text"><br>
        1: <input type="text"><br>
        2: <input type="text"><br>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```